# Sublime Text custom comment behavior

Tags: sublimetext, code-snippets

How do I change Sublime Text's **toggle comment** and **block comment** characters used in a particular file type?

For instance, in **erb** files, I want:`⌘ + /` to apply:

```
<%
=begin

<div>All my html/erb content</div>

<%
=end %>
```

Instead of it's current functionality which still allows erb tags to seep through and break things:

```
<!--
<div>All my html/erb content</div>
-->
```

Comment: Just to clarify - you want the opening comment to be `<% =begin %>` and the closing comment to be `<% =end %>`?

Comment: Yes,and it's important that the = touching the begin/end are always indented 0 amount.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to select

```ruby
puts "This is embedded Ruby!"
```

for example, hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>, and now have it look like this:

```ruby
<%
=begin
puts "This is embedded Ruby!"
=end %>
```

If that is the case, then create a new XML file with **exactly** the following contents, including newlines, etc.:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Comments</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>text.html.ruby</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>shellVariables</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>&lt;%
=begin
</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_END</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>
=end %&gt;</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>4C2E088A-2EDB-44AB-9C62-CE0112B4C237</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Save the file as `Packages/Rails/HTML (Rails) Comments.tmPreferences`, where `Packages` is the folder opened when selecting `Preferences -> Browse Packages...`. On OS X it's `~/Application Support/Sublime Text X/Packages` where `X` is either `2` or `3`, depending on the version of Sublime you're using. If you're using ST2, the `Packages/Rails` folder will already exist, so you can just save the file straightaway. On ST3, `Packages/Rails` (most likely) doesn't exist yet, so you'll have to create it first, then save the file.

Good luck!